# Basic HTML issue

Tags: html

I'm a total newbie to coding, just trying to create a circle for a course, but it's not working.  Can someone help and suggest what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Lesson</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
        #circle = {width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="circle"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `=` from style block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine, except that `=` in `<style>` tags. Just remove that.

```
#circle {width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    }
```